# "The connection is not compressed" from Chrome with SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'm running nginx with SSL on Ubuntu 10.04LTS. Chrome gives me this annoying warning when I inspect the certificate:

```
The connection is not compressed.
```

In the response it looks like it is being sent gzipped though:

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 12 Feb 2012 09:00:38 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx/1.0.5
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.6-13ubuntu3.3`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`The connection is not compressed.` is related to ssl compression, not gzip. Since you response gzip-compressed, there's no need to enable compression on ssl level.

See also: http://www.belshe.com/2010/11/18/ssl-compression-and-you/

Answer (score 5):

Since this question was asked, a serious security vulnerability (the BEAST attack) was discovered making it [possible to compromise an SSL/TLS session if the SSL/TLS session is compressed](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/19911/11291). To mitigate this, both servers and browsers are beginning to disable compression; you will need to use HTTP compression instead, and that only sparingly if at all, to mitigate yet another vulnerability (the CRIME attack).

Comment: Glad you brought this up. I was just reading about it today, as well.

Answer (score 2):

SSL compression is [disabled intentionally in Nginx](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/changeset/4186/nginx). Apparently, to save memory. It may make sense as Chrome is the only browser I know that supports SSL compression.

I use Apache specially for this feature as SSL compression saves a lot of bandwidth by compressing the whole 2-way stream, not just the response body. In my application (ERP web client) the compressed SSL stream uses about 30% to 50% less bandwidth than http compression. So, a lot of bandwidth is saved just by asking users to use Chrome.

If you want to switch to Apache, check [my question](https://serverfault.com/questions/378799/how-to-disable-apache-http-compression-mod-deflate-when-ssl-stream-is-compress) for information about disabling http compression for enhanced performance.